# make select component multiselect dropdown list stay open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using material-ui-next component Select.  It works fairly well.

One place where I use it is within a cell element of an Ag-Grid.  In this use case, I am using the multiselect feature.  It works fairly well.

One small annoyance is that the dropdown closes each time the user clicks on an element to select it, so that in order to select multiple elements, the user must repeatedly re-click the Select element to open its drop down menu each time he or she selects another element.

I have noticed that the example element on the material-ui-next site (https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/) does NOT behave this way.  I cannot see any significant difference between my code and the code on their sample site.  My code is, essentially:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'material-ui-next/Select';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui-next/Menu';

export class CellRenderer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.value;
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState(newProps.value);
    }
    render() {
        var items = ["a","b","c","d"];
        var separator = ";";
        var multiple = true;
        var selects = this.state.split(separator);

        var cellHandler = this.props.cellHandler;
        const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
            var newValue = event.target.value.join(separator);
            cellHandler(newValue);
        };

        return (
            <Select value={selects} onChange={onChangeHandler} autoWidth={true} multiple={multiple} >
                {items.map(x => <MenuItem key={x} value={x}>{x}</MenuItem>)}
            </Select >
        );
    }
}
```

yarn.lock entry for my version of material-ui:

```
material-ui-next@^1.0.0-beta.23:
  version "1.0.0-beta.23"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/material-ui-next/-/material-ui-next-1.0.0-beta.23.tgz#fe76ac6e5fcf85eaa574c24df1c89cbffdc179db"
  dependencies:
    babel-runtime "^6.26.0"
    brcast "^3.0.1"
    classnames "^2.2.5"
    deepmerge "^2.0.1"
    dom-helpers "^3.2.1"
    hoist-non-react-statics "^2.3.1"
    jss "^9.3.3"
    jss-preset-default "^4.0.1"
    keycode "^2.1.9"
    lodash "^4.17.4"
    normalize-scroll-left "^0.1.2"
    prop-types "^15.6.0"
    react-event-listener "^0.5.1"
    react-flow-types "^0.2.0-beta.6"
    react-jss "^8.1.0"
    react-popper "^0.7.4"
    react-scrollbar-size "^2.0.2"
    react-transition-group "^2.2.1"
    recompose "^0.26.0"
    scroll "^2.0.1"
    warning "^3.0.0"
```

Comment: The closing menu is something you cannot control. However, specifying the "size" attribute for _multi_ select results in the select always being expanded. E.g. `<select multi size="4">...</select>`

Comment: @marekful But it behaves differently in the online sample from how it behaves in my use.  In the online sample, it behaves how I want it to behave.  In my use, it does not do what I want.  What is the difference???  (Also, you have "mulit" as the option, not "multiselect" - is that correct?  Are we talking about the same component, the material-ui-next component?)

Comment: Perhaps it is their use of FormControl.  I will try that.

Comment: So when the user selects a value, you're passing that value up to the parent through the `cellHandler` callback, which passes it back down by setting `props.value`?

Comment: @JulesDupont Correct.  (In my handler, as you can see above, I concat the selected values in the Select component value array before passing to parent, and when receiving from parent, I split into array, but that is all just machinery.)  And so, it all _works_ correctly, just very inefficiently from a users perspective.

Comment: Have you resolved your question? Ive stumbled upon similar issue.

Comment: I have the same problem here.. weird.. i am not sending any value to the parent as well.

Comment: same issue here :(

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, every input type, including multiselect, started closing after selection. I noticed it was caused by the wrapper object (grid in my case) having a key (key={`${Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000))}-min`} )  set to it (which apparently causes some re-rendering or something).

Comment: To make this answer more helpful could you give an example that is solving the question/problem.